# Using 'fs' with browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify, fs

How to use `fs` with fs with browserify

require('fs') returns an empty object

```
var fs = require('fs')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. Browserify, by its nature, is Node-style modules *for the web browser*. `fs` is a file system module. You can't access the file system from the web browser, for obvious security reasons. So even if you bundled Node's `fs` module into your web application, it wouldn't — and couldn't — work.

Most if not all of the built-in Node modules are incompatible with use on the browser.

Comment: `path` is compatible IIRC.

Comment: @skiilaa: I knew it was right to hedge my bets. :-D

Comment: any alternatives.

Comment: @SibiRaj - Again: You can't access the file system from the web browser, for obvious security reasons.